# Install windows back on laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, laptop, dell-inspiron

No this is not a question on instructions as to how to install windows.

My laptop came with genuine Windows 8 installed, but I didn't get a CD. After a few months I installed Ubuntu on it for trial purposes, although I want to go back now. I tried installing Windows 7 on it but the one I have is 32 bit while Dell doesn't provide 32 bit drivers for my laptop model.

I want to install Windows 8 back in a legit manner back on my laptop, is there a download link available and a way to get it activated? My laptop doesn't even have a sticker which tells a product key, it just has a sticker of Windows 8 on it.

It is a Dell Inspiron 14R-5421. Any way available other than the customer care, and will they install it back, I mean I did give money for original Windows though I didn't get a CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You laptop might have a sticker on the bottom with Windows License key. You can use that when installing OS.

If there are no stickers and you had Windows 8, then your laptop most likely uses UEFI Secure Boot with license information stored in UEFI partition. For this, you should be able to just install Windows version that you had and Windows should pick-up the license from UEFI partition during setup.

Comment: All Windows 8 machines must support two things. UEFI and Secure Boot. Additionally Secure Boot must have the ability to be disabled. Both of these are required for an OEM to sell their product with Windows 8 one it.  **Additionally ALL Windows 8 machines store the license in the BIOS.**

Comment: Well the terrible thing is, my brother while installing Ubuntu wiped all partitions :/

Comment: @Ramhound Since wiping all partitions wouldn't have wiped the BIOS, so in a way I can install legit windows 8 right?

Comment: @KartikAnand - Your OEM can provide you an installation disk.  As indicated the Windows 8 installer will automatically detect the license key.  There are other ways to get a `Windows 8` installation media just not any I can suggest.

Comment: @KartikAnand - Of course there is proof.  Dell can provide you the required media to do so.

Comment: You don't need to take it to dell. Just download an official ISO from Microsoft and go ahead install it. It will pickup the license. I once did this ona a Lenovo, it even switched boot logo to lenovo one without me needign to install via Lenovo OEM disk. I just use an iso from msdn.

Comment: @edvinas.me where can I download the official ISO I can't see any link on Microsoft's website?

Comment: @edvinas.me and you sure that the fact that all my partitions have been wiped out by Ubuntu won't do any harm?

Comment: @edvinas.me It says here I need a product key? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only

Comment: UEFI partition is stored in BIOS, not your hard-drive.

Comment: @Kartik: with that site you will need windows running to launch the setup. To download off MSDN you need subscription, there are other ways to get original .iso images which I can't suggest here though. You are on your own for this :)

Comment: @edvinas.me Well yes I know what you mean ;) I thought they do provide a direct download link :D

Comment: For Windows 7 they do, but I could not find anything regarding Windows 8.

Comment: @edvinas.me Just for the record. Can I install windows 7 with an activated windows 8 product key ? :D

Comment: You cannot use the upgrade installer to download a non-upgrade version of Windows 8. It also cannot be used to download Windows 8.1 because the license is an OEM license.  **You need to talk to Dell**  Why are you resistant to that solution?

Comment: @Ramhound The only reason is that they would require my laptop for 2-3 days for a process I personally know completes in less than an hour. I don't trust them :D

Comment: @KartikAnand - **Dell does not require your laptop to send you the installation media in the mail or hand you a disk.**

Comment: @Ramhound I guess they'll charge me for a physical disk then! I mean if they didn't give it to me in the first place why would they give it to me now. Dell representatives in India assume we don't have a clue about computers and generally tend to be bullies. The HP guy gave me the original OEM disc with the laptop.

Comment: @edvinas.me - You are leading Kartik down the wrong path.  He does not have a working Windows installation so your suggestion isn't even possible.  Even if there was a working Windows installation the installer you suggest requires certain license types and will not accept other license types ( i.e. System Builder and OEM ) licenses.

Comment: @KartikAnand - Its typical for the OEMs not to provide these disks because of the restoration partition that exists.  Since that was wiped you have no other option to get an installation disk.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I'll contact Dell first thing in the morning tomorrow and fight for my rights :D

Comment: Simple option is to get OEM CD and install it and it will pickup the license via secure boot. Any OEM cd will do.

Comment: Take this discussion to [chat], please. Comments are not meant for extended talks.

Answer (score -1):

I would do a factory restore and restore the computers backup image. Once complete you will have a lot of updates to complete.To enter Factory restore is either F12 or F8 before the dell logo

Comment: And which partition would contain the information for this? One of the wiped ones?